# angular2 bind numeric value to html element

Tags: angular

The flow of operations relevant for this problem is as follows:
**Home component calls a method in Cart component and Cart component calls a method in Cart service.**

Home template:

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" (click)="addToCart(specific_hall)">Add to cart</button>
```

Home component:

```
export class Home {

    halls: Object;
    specific_hall: Object;
    cart : any;

    public cartInstance: Cart= new Cart(this.cartService);


    constructor(private homeService: HomeService, private cartService: CartService){

        this.cart=[];
    }

    addToCart(item: any){

        this.cart.push(item)
        this.cartInstance.addToCart(item)   
    }
}
```

I have a Cart component as follows:

```
export class Cart {

    cartItems: any;
    cartItemCount : number;

    constructor(private cartService: CartService){

        this.cartItems=[];
        this.cartItemCount=0;
    }


    addToCart(item: Object): void {

        this.cartItems.push(this.cartService.addToCart(item))
        console.log(this.cartItems.length)

        this.cartItemCount=this.cartItems.length;
    }
}
```

My cart service is as follows:

```
export class CartService{

    cart : any;
    constructor(){

        this.cart=[];
    }

    addToCart(item: any): any {

        this.cart.push(item);
        return this.cart;
    }
}
```

cart template has following code:

```
<span> Items in the cart: {{cartItemCount}} </span>
```

Even if I add elements to the cart my cart template always shows 0 in the above line. `console.log(this.cartItems.length)` this line in cart template however always shows correct number.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check after making below change :

```
addToCart(item: Object): void {
    this.cartItems = this.cartService.addToCart(item);
    console.log(this.cartItems.length)
    this.cartItemCount=this.cartItems.length;
}
```

Comment: It's same, didn't help! I had it like this before, then I modified to above code.